# How are classes accessed in browser between files without import/export? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, import, export

I understand that by putting the html files in the correct order in the HTML file, classes can be accessed between files without using ES6 import/export. I suppose my question is, why/how is this? Why do we have to import/export functions and variables, but not classes?

Comment: what do you mean by import / export functions and variables?

Answer (score 0):

Classes can be passed between script files by declaring them in global scope. Problems arise if an attempt is made to access a class in a script (file) before including a script that defines the class - the class doesn't exist when first referenced.

It is also possible to generate errors by declaring the same global `const`, `let` or `class` names in multiple files, or corrupt the workings of one script by declaring (var`) variables or functions of the same name in a later script.

For these reasons it is not advisable to use global variables in an unrestricted fashion in a production app.

A first line of defense can be to include all code for a library in an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) and only define a single global entry point to the library. JQuery is an example of this approach with only `$` and its `jQuery` alias defined globally.

JavaScript source files of type "module" provide a more recent alternative. The `import` statement imports values from a named JavaScript file rather than trying to define and later access them in global name space.

Comment: oh okay, thank you! So all variables in the global scope can be accessed without having to import? Because I thought that if you had a variable like "const a=10", it won't be available inside other js files without being exported - but classes can be. Is that correct?

Comment: @lisaostman What you thought was incorrect. Code in standard JavaScript files is compiled in global scope - hence all file level declarations in the file are in global scope ( and available across files if included in the right order).  JavaScript files of type "module" are the workaround - file level declarations are not in global scope and must be explicitly exported to become available outside the module - then to be imported from the file by code using the exported values.